# cant compile raylib for web

Tags: html, web, raylib

I have been trying to compile my raylib game to web (following this tutorial https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-for-Web-(HTML5) ) and i got stuck on this part:

```
Before compiling raylib, make sure all paths to emscripten (EMSDK_PATH) and tools are correctly configured on
 C:/raylib/raylib/src/Makefile, you must verify these lines.

To compile raylib source code, just execute Notepad++ script: raylib_makefile and SET PLATFORM=PLATFORM_WEB.
 To do this, start up Notepad++ for raylib, open the raylib.h file, press F6, choose raylib_makefile, verify that
 in the script SET PLATFORM=PLATFORM_WEB, then click OK to run the script. That script just calls the following make
 line (in case you're are working on a custom environment):

make PLATFORM=PLATFORM_WEB -B
```

When i open C:\raylib\raylib\src\raylib.h in notepad++ and press F6 nothing happens and when i try to call make `PLATFORM=PLATFORM_WEB -B` in the powershell it says

```
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ make PLATFORM=PLATFORM_WEB -B
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in the command line:

make -e PLATFORM=PLATFORM_WEB -B

For more information check this video which describe the procedure to complile a raylib game from start to finish.

https://youtu.be/j6akryezlzc